# Is an Observer a 'listener' to an Observable in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm learning RxJS and am rather confused as to where the "listeners" are (in the Observable or the Observer), how they are subscribed/unsubscribed, and what happens when an Observer is "no longer interested in" an Observable, such as when you use `take` or `takeUntil`.

For the first part -- what's subscribed to what, what's a listener -- I'm confused by the seeming contradiction between these statements.  From http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html we read that Observers are not 'listeners' to Observables

> This is drastically different to event handler APIs like
>   addEventListener / removeEventListener. With observable.subscribe, the
>   given Observer is not registered as a listener in the Observable. The
>   Observable does not even maintain a list of attached Observers.

but in http://reactivex.io/learnrx/ it says (Exercise 30) (highlighting mine) that

> An Observable based on an Event will never complete on its own. The
>   take() function creates a new sequence that completes after a discrete
>   number of items arrive. This is important, **because unlike an Event,
>   when an Observable sequence completes it unsubscribes all of its
>   listeners**. That means that if we use take() to complete our Event
>   sequence, we don't need to unsubscribe!

This seems contradictory to me.  When you set up an Observable with, for example, `fromEvent`, where is the event listener? When you use `take(1)`, for instance, on an Observable based on DOM events, what happens after the first event is sent to the observer?  Does the Observer *unsubscribe* from the Observable, which continues to emit events, it's just that the Observer isn't listening to them anymore?  Or does the Observable somehow unsubscribe the Observer, that is, the eventListener was in the Observable, not the Observer?

Thanks for any clues -- obviously I'm not seeing the forest for the trees, but the tutorials I'm working through, while they are good at trying to explain it conceptually, leave me confused as to what's actually going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part is being rather particular about its use of words in order to highlight that subscribing to an observable is a matter of calling a function (or more likely a chain of functions) to run all the code they contain. The second part is less particular about its wording, but it's not really talking about the same thing. If you like, the second part would be better worded as "when an observable completes, it calls teardown logic on its observers.

Let me try to describe what i mean when i say that subscribing to an observable is a matter of calling a chain of functions. Consider the following super simple example:

For a super simple example, suppose i create this observable:

```
const justOne = Rx.Observable.create(function realSubscribe(observer) {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.complete();
});

justOne.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

If i then call `justOne.subscribe(val => console.log(val))`, doing so will immediately call the function i named realSubscribe. It then does `observer.next(1)`, which results in logging out val, then it does `observer.complete()`. And that's it.

No where in this process did the observable create or augment a list of subscribers; it just ran through the code sequentially and then was done.

---

Now moving onto a slightly more realistic example, let's consider `fromEvent`. If i were to implement it, it might look something like this (the [real implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/fromEvent.ts) is more complicated, but this gets the gist of it):

```
function fromEvent(element, eventName) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(function subscribeToEvent(observer) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, observer.next);
    return function cleanup() {
      element.removeEventListener(eventName, observer.next);
    }
  });
}

const observable = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const subscription = observable.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
```

Now when i call observable.subscribe, it runs subscribeToEvent, and in so doing it calls addEventListener on the document. document.addEventListener **does** result in the document keeping a list of event listeners, but that's because of the way addEventListener is implemented, not something common to all observables. The observable itself doesn't keep track of any listeners. It just calls what it's told to call, and then returns a cleanup function.

---

Next up let's look at take. As before the [real implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/take.ts) is more complicated, but here's roughly what it does:

```
// In the real `take`, you don't need to pass in another observable since that's
// available automatically from the context you called it in. But my sample code
// has to get it somehow.
function take(count, otherObservable) {
  return new Observable(function subscribeToTake(observer) {
    let soFar = 0;
    otherObservable.subscribe((value) => {
      observer.next(value);
      soFar++;
      if (soFar >= count) {
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
  });
}

const clickObservable = fromEvent(document, 'click');
take(1, clickObservable).subscribe(event => console.log(event))
```

As mentioned in the comment, the syntax i'm using doesn't quite match how it would be use in rxjs, but that's because to mimic that would require a more full implementation. Anyway, the main thing to draw your attention to is that we're starting to produce a chain of functions:

When i call `.subscribe`, that calls subscribeToTake. This sets up a counter, and then calls otherObservable.subscribe, which is subscribeToEvent. subscribeToEvent then calls document.addEventListener.

Take's job is to sit in the middle of this function chain. It keeps track of how many values have been emitted so far. If the count is low enough, it just forwards the values along. But once the count is reached, it will call complete, thus ending the observable. Calling complete causes the observable to run any teardown logic it has, or anything its chain has. There's no teardown logic for `take`, but `fromEvent` will run some teardown logic to remove the event listener.

Comment: First code sample clear to me, but the second raises some questions.  Here `take` is getting the observable on which it's acting, but also returning a new observable? In `otherObservable.subscribe()`, the function you're passing in is the `next` function for the subscribed Observer, but inside _this_  you call `observer.next()`  Why?  Finally, the part that is throwing me is " Calling complete causes the observable to run any teardown logic it has, or anything its chain has".  How?  I thought calling 'complete' only signalled to the Observer.  How does it signal to the Observable?

Comment: `[take is] also returning a new observable?` Yes. Each of the operators will produce a new observable. `inside this you call observer.next() Why?` fromEvent will tell take when an event happens, and then the code you're asking about is take forwarding that event on. Without it, console.log would not get called. `[How does teardown logic get called]`. I believe that code is contained in the Subscription object: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts

Comment: So the Observer passed to `new Observable(function subscribeToTake(observer)` is different than the implied observer passed to `otherObservable.subscribe((value)`?  That is, the function `(value) => {
      observer.next(value);...` is the `next` function of some observer, but not the same observer that's subscribing to take?  Then let's call this second observer 'observer2'.  So first `observer2.next` is called, which calls `observer.next`?

Comment: There is quite good explanation of difference between observer and subscriber in Michael Hladky talk https://youtu.be/y2aBiA5N4h8